# ArrayList and Map problem in grails

Tags: exception, grails, arrays, dictionary

I have a service that contains a map:

```
static Map cargosMap = ['1':'item1','2':'item 2','3':'item 3']
```

that is returned via a method in the service:

```
 static Map getCargos() {
    [cargosMap]
 }
```

A controller calls it like this:

```
def mform = {

    Map cargos = empService.getCargos()

    [cargos:cargos]
}
```

In the gsp, I have the select:

```
<g:select name="cg1" from="${cargos}" />
```

But I'm getting the exception:

```
 Error 500: Executing action  ....caused exception: 
   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object
   ...  
   with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 
  'java.util.Map'
```

Any clues ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you're wrapping the map in an ArrayList in `getCargos()`. Why not just: `static getCargos() { cargosMap }`. Or, better yet, just rename `cargosMap` to `cargos` and Groovy will create the getter for you.